# How To Get Records Opening Stock and Closing Stock Using Sql-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am new in sql server.

How to display record Opening stock and Closing Stock?

I don't know how to display record Table Formate in SQL Server query?

please help me

**My Table**

```
Ttype       ItemName         TDate          DC          Qty

 LGR        VANILA          08-04-2018      C           10
 GRN        VANILA          08-04-2018      C           10
 GRN        VANILA          09-04-2018      C           20
 DA         VANILA          10-04-2018      D           10
 DA         VANILA          10-04-2018      D           10       
 GRN        VANILA          11-04-2018      C           10
 DA         VANILA          12-04-2018      D           10
```

> Start Date : 11-04-2018 End Date : 12-04-2018

**Expected output**

```
Ttype       ItemName         TDate          DC          Qty   

Op.St        VANILA         11-04-2018      C           20
GRN          VANILA         11-04-2018      C           10
DA           VANILA         12-04-2018      D           10
Cl.St        VANILA         12-04-2018      C           20
```

Comment: i don't know why down vote?

Comment: any mistake for my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As variant you can use 3 queries with `UNION ALL`

```
DECLARE
  @StartDate date='20180411',
  @EndDate date='20180412'

SELECT
  1 RowType,
  'Op.St' Ttype,
  ItemName,
  @StartDate TDate,
  IIF(SUM(IIF(DC='D',1,-1)*Qty)<0,'C','D') DC,
  ABS(SUM(IIF(DC='D',1,-1)*Qty)) Qty
FROM MyTable
WHERE TDate<@StartDate
GROUP BY ItemName

UNION ALL

SELECT
  2 RowType,
  Ttype,
  ItemName,
  TDate,
  DC,
  Qty
FROM MyTable
WHERE TDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

UNION ALL

SELECT
  3 RowType,
  'Cl.St' Ttype,
  ItemName,
  @EndDate TDate,
  IIF(SUM(IIF(DC='D',1,-1)*Qty)<0,'C','D') DC,
  ABS(SUM(IIF(DC='D',1,-1)*Qty)) Qty
FROM MyTable
WHERE TDate<=@EndDate
GROUP BY ItemName

ORDER BY RowType,TDate
```

I think this way is clear to understand.

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec687/1

One more variant

```
DECLARE
  @StartDate date='20180411',
  @EndDate date='20180422'

SELECT
  1 RowType,
  'Op.St' Ttype,
  d.ItemName,
  m.TDate,
  IIF(d.Qty<0,'C','D') DC,
  ABS(d.Qty) Qty
FROM (SELECT @StartDate TDate) m
OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT ItemName,SUM(IIF(DC='D',1,-1)*Qty) Qty
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE TDate<m.TDate
    GROUP BY ItemName
  ) d

UNION ALL

SELECT
  2 RowType,
  Ttype,
  ItemName,
  TDate,
  DC,
  Qty
FROM MyTable
WHERE TDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

UNION ALL

SELECT
  3 RowType,
  'Cl.St' Ttype,
  d.ItemName,
  m.TDate,
  IIF(d.Qty<0,'C','D') DC,
  ABS(d.Qty) Qty
FROM (SELECT @EndDate TDate) m
OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT ItemName,SUM(IIF(DC='D',1,-1)*Qty) Qty
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE TDate<=m.TDate
    GROUP BY ItemName
  ) d

ORDER BY RowType,TDate
```

You can use the second variant if you want to get rows `Op.St` and `Cl.St` anyway (for example you can set `@StartDate='20180401'` and `@EndDate='20180422'`)

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec687/4

Comment: @Genish Parvadia - I've added one more variant into my answer. It's return the rows `Op.St` and `Cl.St` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit headache for me with `lead()` and `lag()` functions with `union all`

```
;with cte as (
    select 1 as Sort, 'Op.St' Ttype, null ItemName, null TDate, null DC, null Qty union all
    select 2 as Sort, Ttype, ItemName, TDate, DC, Qty from table t
    where tdate >= '20180411' and tdate <= '20180412' union all
    select 3 as Sort, 'Cl.St' Ttype, null ItemName, null TDate, null DC, null Qty
)

select  Ttype, 
        case (sort) when 1 then lead(ItemName) over (order by sort) 
                    when 3 then lag(ItemName) over (order by sort) else ItemName end ItemName ,
        case (sort) when 1 then lead(TDate) over (order by sort) 
                    when 3 then lag(TDate) over (order by sort) else TDate end TDate,
        case (sort) when 1 then lead(DC) over (order by sort) 
                    when 3 then lag(DC) over (order by sort) else DC end DC,
        case when sort <> 2 then (select sum(Qty) from cte c) else Qty end Qty 
from cte c
```

Comment: Show Error? All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @GenishParvadia... you just need to specify the `columns` list in `cte` instead of `*`.

Comment: @GenishParvadia.. you have some typo at last line of `DC` it would be `C` or `D` ?